# "Scale range" vs "Scale dependent visibility" when labeling features using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, scale, rendering

What is the difference between "Scale range" vs "Scale dependent visibility" settings when labeling features using QGIS?

From my perspective they are identical.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may set different labels for different scale ranges. E.g. pink labels for 1:1000 to 1:10000, red labels for 1:10001 to 1:25000.

You may set a scale dependent visibility for all of you labels. E.g. no labels are visibile above 1:25000.

Comment: Wouldnt that be taken care of by the scale range anyways? I still feel like the scale dependent visibility is redundant in the case of rule based rendering. 
Isnt scale depenendent visibility ment to be used with "single lables" renderer instead of "rule-based" ?

Comment: But does it hurt to have access to it @JanHorak?

Comment: It doesnt. I just wondered if it has some deliberate purpous or some unknown interaction. I agree that from developement point of view its simpler to have same "rendering" tab in single lable option as well as rule based.