# When creating layout using vectored map the text containing place names disappears in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules, mgrs

Zooming past 112% in the layout view kills the text containing place names. The same happens on export.

I'm using QLRs from Lantmäteriet. Topografi 50 Vector, to be specific.

I also need my eventual maps to be in MGRS. So I am using ["Military Grids" project.](https://plugins.qgis.org/geopackages/7/). This seems to be where it goes borked, as a fresh project doesn't do the thing. Only using that project.

Scale dependent options aren't ticked. The layer is a points layer that generates text.

I need it to be visible at 1:50000 and 1:25000 and sadly Lantmäteriet doesn't provide topo maps in 1:25000 anymore. So I'm stuck with that.

I am VERY new to QGIS...

[image: 1:50k, no text.]

[image: 1:25k, text]

In the main view, the text shows up in 50k too.

Comment: It could be scale dependent labels https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387019/scale-range-vs-scale-dependent-visibility-when-labeling-features-using-qgis though I'm not familiar with that data so I'm just taking a stab, is it a web service?  Please expand on 'kills the text', does the text fail to draw or does it get so big it fills the whole screen?

Comment: It fails to draw. 
It is, sort of. It's the Swedish Mapping Agency. 
I've tried changing that to both be off and on, as well as in my wanted range. It's a point layer with symbols, FWIW

Comment: Welcome - Please include some screenshots of the behaviour + style settings and clearer descriptions to make it easier for people to assist, It's hard to work out where the issue is. Contributors can't be expected to hunt down the source data and .qlr file to see for themselves. What CRSes are you using, do they work with the linked Military Grids project (you read the metadata?)

Comment: I'm using SWEREF 99TM which is UTM33. UTM33 is the default CRS for the project. It doesn't matter if I have SWEREF99TM or UTM33 as the CRS, it happens with both.  Not really sure where i might find style settings (i've only copied the style from other stuff thus far). But i did edit my post with the screnshots of the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by going into the layer group, "Rule based labeling", and deselecting the rule based scaling for every entity. It was set to 0 > 1:50001 which somehow made it decide to not show it at 1:50000. But it's fixed now... On to the next issue.